# Как получить сектора, на которых расположен файл?

Tags: c#, файлы, файловая-система, ntfs, fat32

В общем нужно получить сектора, на которых расположен файл и перезаписать их. Каким образом это можно осуществить на C#? Может кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Низкоуровневый доступ к диску и парсинг ФС. И .NET для этого мало подходит, сразу говорю.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ну можно и на плюсах :) В сторону каких либ смотреть?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону WinAPI

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов пошарился по WinApi. Там только на высоком уровне предоставляется доступ. Вроде создания/поиска файлов.

Comment: Доступ к секторам есть через тот же CreateFile. Читайте внимательнее MSDN

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Спасибо

Comment: нашлось решение?

Answer (score 2):

Прямой доступ к секторам запоминающего устройства в C# можно осуществить следующим образом ([но начиная с Windows Vista этот код подойдёт только для чтения](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/942448/changes-to-the-file-system-and-to-the-storage-stack-to-restrict-direct-disk-access-and-direct-volume-access-in-windows-vista-and-in-windows-server-2008)):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
        const uint GENERIC_READ  = 0x80000000;
        const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile
        (
            string FileName,
            uint DesiredAccess,
            uint ShareMode,
            uint SecurityAttributes,
            uint CreationDisposition,
            uint FlagsAndAttributes,
            int hTemplateFile
        );

        static void Main()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

            // PhysicalDrive2 - имя целевого привода
            using (SafeFileHandle handle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive2", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0))
            {
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(handle, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    int sector = 35792;

                    // Read
                    stream.Position = 512 * sector;
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 512);

                    // Write (начиная с Windows Vista требует дополнительных манипуляций)
                    stream.Position = 512 * sector;
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, 512);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++) Console.Write(buffer[i].ToString() + ' ');
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Не смотря на то, что позиция в данном случае указывается в байтах, так же, как это происходит при работе с памятью через драйвер файловой системы, обращение будет произведено именно к тому сектору, в котором расположен указанный байт.

То есть в случае, если `stream.Position = 600`, чтение будет произведено с самого начала первого сектора — так, как будто `stream.Position = 512`, то есть с начала ячейки памяти.

## Особенности работы в ОС начиная с Windows Vista

---

Для того, чтобы получить объект `SafeFileHandle`, запускать программу нужно с правами администратора.

---

Без дополнительных манипуляций доступны для перезаписи:

- загрузочный сектор логического раздела [BPB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_BIOS) (*англ.* BIOS parameter block), однако его резервная копия без дополнительных манипуляций не доступна, равно как и все остальные сектора логического раздела ([Condition 1](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/942448/changes-to-the-file-system-and-to-the-storage-stack-to-restrict-direct-disk-access-and-direct-volume-access-in-windows-vista-and-in-windows-server-2008));
- сектора, не принадлежащие ни одному логическому разделу, например сектор с [MBR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) (*англ.* master boot record) и зарезервированное за ним пространство, или сектора, не отнесённые ни к одному логическому разделу по другим причинам ([Condition 2](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/942448/changes-to-the-file-system-and-to-the-storage-stack-to-restrict-direct-disk-access-and-direct-volume-access-in-windows-vista-and-in-windows-server-2008)).

Условия доступа к секторам, принадлежащим логическим разделам:

- неявная блокировка раздела, посредством запроса эксклюзивного доступа для записи ([Condition 3](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/942448/changes-to-the-file-system-and-to-the-storage-stack-to-restrict-direct-disk-access-and-direct-volume-access-in-windows-vista-and-in-windows-server-2008));
- явная блокировка раздела, посредством отправки запроса на блокировку и запроса на отключение ([Condition 4](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/942448/changes-to-the-file-system-and-to-the-storage-stack-to-restrict-direct-disk-access-and-direct-volume-access-in-windows-vista-and-in-windows-server-2008));
- запрос на запись с флагом `SL_FORCE_DIRECT_WRITE` ([Condition 5](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/942448/changes-to-the-file-system-and-to-the-storage-stack-to-restrict-direct-disk-access-and-direct-volume-access-in-windows-vista-and-in-windows-server-2008)).

*To be continued...*

## FAT32

Список секторов, на которых расположен файл, вычисляется из его кластерной цепочки.

Начало кластерной цепочки хранится в записи о файле в директории, в которой он лежит.

*To be continued...*

Comment: Спасибо! А записать никак не выйдет на новых версиях?

Comment: @ProfessorFortran , скорее всего можно, но я пока проверил только Condition 1-2. Как проверю остальное - прокомментирую. А может вы и сами разберётесь раньше.